# Plot points in map d3 javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, plot

i want to draw on map base on longitude and latitude in csv file called tree.csv on a map that i using an image . 
My csv file include many lines ,so i will just put some lines here

Longitude            Latitude

37.7295482207565      122.392689419827

37.8030467266869      122.425063628702
......
Here is my code

```
d3.csv("/trees.csv", function(data) {
    dataset=data.map(function(d) { return [+d["Longitude"],+d["Latitude"] ];});
    console.log(data)
    var width = 750,
    height = width;

    // Set up projection that map is using
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
     .center([-122.433701, 37.767683])

     .scale(225000)
     .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    var path=d3.geo.path().projection(projection);


    var svgContainer=d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",width)
    .attr("height",height);
    svgContainer.append("image")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height)
     .attr("xlink:href", "/Ilu.svg");

    var trees=svgContainer.selectAll("circles")
    .data(data).enter()
    .append("circles")

    var treesAttributes=trees
    .attr("cx",function(d) { return projection(d["Longitude"])[0];})
    .attr("cy",function(d) { return projection(d["Latitude"])[1];})
    .attr("r","100px")
    .style("fill","red");
```

I can see my map but i cant see any  points on my map . When i inspect the web. i see that cx is Nan number ,and cy is same number. I think maybe my array havent been read yet. But i am not sure about the problems. I have been stucked. Can you guys solve me the problem ? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Maybe remove the subset `[0]` and `[1]`?

Comment: @RyanMorton Thanks for your answer . The coordinator cx and cy has different number with the the number in picture now but they are still the same number with other lines and  there is still no points on map

Comment: Ignore the previous comment. What does the data look like? It seems strange that you send either the lat or long to the projection function.  Shouldn't both coordinates go to the projection together to properly evaluate the cx and cy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in that you aren't providing coordinates to be projected.

A d3 geoProjection takes a longitude latitude pair and projects it to an x,y svg coordinate (a projection returns a coordinate as: [x,y], which is why you use this form in your code: `projection(coord)[0]` to get the cx value). You are seeking to project only a longitude, and then only a latitude:

```
.attr("cx",function(d) { return projection(d["Longitude"])[0];})
.attr("cy",function(d) { return projection(d["Latitude"])[1];})
```

In this case, `projection` won't return an svg coordinate as you aren't providing a geographical coordinate to project. You need to project both longitude and latitude, becuase x and y values produced in a projection are usually (not always) co-dependent - in any conical projection for example, the output y (or x) value is dependent on both latitude and longitude. Further, as projection() returns [x,y], it requires both longitude and latitude for every projection.

Instead try:

```
.attr("cx",function(d) { return projection([d["Longitude"],d["Latitude"]])[0];})
.attr("cy",function(d) { return projection([d["Longitude"],d["Latitude"]])[1];})
```

Remeber that d3 geoprojections expect the form: `projection([longitude, latitude])`, changing the order of longitude and latitude will produce unexpected results.

```js
var data = [
{longitude:1,latitude:1},
{longitude:-1,latitude:1},
{longitude:1,latitude:-1},
{longitude:-1,latitude:-1}
]

var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width",200)
   .attr("height",200);
   
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
  .translate([100,100]);
  
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx",function(d) { return projection([d.longitude,d.latitude])[0];
   })
  .attr("cy",function(d) { return projection([d["longitude"],d["latitude"]])[1];
   })
   .attr("r",2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```