# Plotting locations on a world map with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I'm plotting locations from a large cvs file with approx 181000 rows, on a world map with d3.js. Since Im new to d3 im having a bit of a trouble with the projections.

The code I have tried is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>svg{width:100%;height:500px;margin:0px auto;}</style>
<body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@4"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@3"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(d3.geoMercator());
d3.json("https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1/world/110m.json", function(error, world) {
  if (error) throw error;
  svg.selectAll("path")
     .data(topojson.feature(world,world.objects.countries).features)
     .enter().append("path")
     .attr("d", path);
});

d3.csv("vis.csv", function(error, data){
  if (error) throw error;
    svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data).enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (data) { return data.latitude })
    .attr("cy", function (data) { return data.longitude })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr('fill', function (d) { return "blue" })
    .attr('stroke','yellow')
})


</script>
```

What is happening is I cannot get the locations to coincide with the points on the map, and they just clump together and are visible on the top end corner of the map. I cannot figure how to fix this.

Comment: Did you scale the lat and long to your canvas width and height?

Comment: I tried to but it's not working for me, I tried to put it as an attribute, and I tried to use translate. I'm not sure what should be the correct command

Comment: The projection handles the scaling - the default projection parameters assume a svg width of 960 pixels and a height of 500 pixels. The obvious issue is that you aren't projecting your latitude and longitude - you are just taking the latitude and longitude values and converting them to pixel values with no transform. Generally you would use `projection([long,lat])` to get [x,y] in pixels, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47822510/7106086), which assuming your csv has headers "latitude" and "longitude" should solve your issue.

Comment: OMG Thankyou  so much @AndrewReid You're right. That solved it.